Is it possible to include a Figure's number without any caption in R Markdown?
Is it possible to include a Figure's number without any caption in R Markdown (simply "Figure X"? And furthermore, is it posible that the word "Figure" is followed by "." instead of ":"?

If it is possible to use quarto instead, you could easily accomplish this by following this guide.#
